# How to Set the Space Between the Footnote Line and First Footnote; then a Different Space Between the Footnotes

Tags: spacing, pdftex, footnotes, vertical-spacing

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{15pt}
\begin{document}
A sentence.\footnote{\lipsum*[31]}
A sentence.\footnote{\lipsum*[31]}
\end{document}
```

which produces the footnotes:

[image]

When I rerun the code using `\setlength{\footnotesep}{15pt}`, I get

[image]

As you can see, the spacing between two consecutive footnotes is equivalent to the space between the footnote line and the first footnote.

But I would like to be able to *separately* adjust the space between (1) the footnote line and the first footnote, and (2) the space between the footnotes themselves.

QUESTION: Say that I would like to have a 10pt space for (1) and a 5pt space between consecutive footnotes. Is there a way to simply accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the command `\footnoterule` to back up the excessive amount.

```
\let\ltxfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \ltxfootnoterule
  \kern-5pt% back up
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\ltxfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \ltxfootnoterule
  \kern-5pt% back up
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{15pt}
\begin{document}
A sentence.\footnote{\lipsum*[31]}
A sentence.\footnote{\lipsum*[31]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer.